# access Auth() object from TryAuthenticate

Tags: c#, authentication, servicestack

I am logging into my service from a c# client like so:

```
serviceClient.Send<ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Auth.AuthResponse>(
     new ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.Auth.Auth() { 
         UserName = "xxx", 
         Password = "yyy" }
 );
```

I would now like to use one of the unused strings in the Auth class to pass some additional information (like a programid).  I am using my own subclassed CredentialsAuthProvider.  Two questions:

1. Do you recommend any of the "extra" properties in the Auth class to stuff my programid over any others? I was considering using "State", will that mess anything up if I put a string in there?
2. Is there a way from within the TryAuthenticate override of my CredentialsAuthProvider to access the Auth class instance that was sent to me (so I can access the programid that I stuck into the State property).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Answered half of my question.

1. Not sure if any of the properties are better than any other, but I'm using "State" to stuff some extra data.  Now that multiple end user programs are accessing the same service, sending a program ID in the State property lets me log the programs attempting to log into the service, along with the users.
2. If you are authenticating by overriding CredentialsAuthProvider, you can override the Authenticate method to gain access to the Authenticate object that is passed in from the user.  From there, you can read the State property (or any other).